# API docs titled "v2.0"; should be "v2.1"

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, api-v2.1

The documentation is titled "StackExchange API v2.0"... this should be updated to "v2.1" as it's not readily obvious that version 2.1 has been published otherwise.

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the 2.1 documentation, it's just the title (and perhaps the first sentence) that hasn't been updated.

All of the [routes added in 2.1](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log) are there, so you don't have to worry that it's missing anything important.

Comment: Yeah... I mean that's what I figured. That's why I tagged my question under "bug". Hopefully someone will see this and update the docs, because it's not readily obvious from the documentation that v2.1 has been released.